# Problems with ComboBox used for showing suggestions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I’m trying to implement suggestions ComboBox like Google’s one:

[image]

User enters several symbols and a list with suggestions appears. 
So I have the following code:

```
 <!--Search query textBox-->
    <ComboBox x:Name="txtMain" IsEditable="True"                                         TextBoxBase.SelectionChanged="txtMain_SelectionChanged"
    TextBoxBase.TextChanged=" txtMain_TextChanged"
    KeyDown="txtMain_PreviewKeyDown"
    SelectionChanged=" txtMain_SelectionChanged"                                              IsTextSearchEnabled="False" />

   public SearchControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _search = new SearchViewModel(doc);

        _suggestionCom = new SuggestionsCommand(
            (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs evarg) =>
            {
                List<string> results = _suggestionCom.Suggestions;

                if (results != null && results.Count() > 0)
                {
                    txtMain.ItemsSource = results;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtMain.ItemsSource = null;
                }
                txtMain.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            });
    }
   void autoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_prevText.Equals(txtMain.Text))
                return;
            // Only autocomplete when there is text
            if (txtMain.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                string lastInput = txtMain.Text;
                _prevText = lastInput;
                _suggestionCom.Execute(lastInput); //it starts a new thread which download suggestions from the service
            }
            else
            {
                txtMain.ItemsSource = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }

    void txtMain_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            if (txtMain.SelectedIndex < txtMain.Items.Count)
            {
                txtMain.SelectedIndex = txtMain.SelectedIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            if (txtMain.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                txtMain.SelectedIndex = txtMain.SelectedIndex - 1;
            }
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // Commit the selection
            //txtMain.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            e.Handled = (e.Key == Key.Enter);
            //Perform search here
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            // Cancel the selection
            txtMain.ItemsSource = null;
            //suggestionListBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Lambda described in the constructor is called when suggestions have been downloaded.
I have the following problems with this code. First, I can’t handle Key.Down (txtMain_PreviewKeyDown is not called when it is pressed). So in order to choose suggestion from a list user need to use mouse. Second, when some suggestions have been found and list has been dropped the text in ComboBox becomes selected (blue) which is not what I want(I don't want to have the text beeing selected when suggestion have been chosen):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AutoCompleteBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28VS.95%29.aspx) is better suited to handle this sort of behaviour.

Comment: It is in Silverlight only. I use WPF

Comment: I'm using it fine in WPF. If you're not on .NET 4.0 it's part of the WPF Toolkit: http://wpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

for one, you should use "PreviewKeyDown" instead of "KeyDown" in you xaml in this case, as you want a tunnelling event. then, you will probably have to override the "focus" method in order to remove the selection on the text.

but as far as I'm concerned, I'd go for an attached property, as described in this other question's answer:

[Is this the best way to build AutoSuggest into a WPF ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519192/is-this-the-best-way-to-build-autosuggest-into-a-wpf-combobox/1519305#1519305)

you might also want to go for the autoComplete TextBox rather than comboBox:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFAutoCompleteTextbox.aspx

and

http://www.lazarciuc.ro/ioan/2008/06/01/auto-complete-for-textboxes-in-wpf/

(I don't like to reinvent the wheel ;-) )

Comment: Thank you for the advice about focus and Preview. I tried various autocompleTextBoxes implementations - all of them are inpractical. One I really like is AutoCompleteBox from WPF ToolKit, hovewer customers are not happy with Ms-PL license.